# Control raspberry pi through a web interface without internet

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch, web-interface

I'd like to control my Raspberry pi 3 Model B (using raspbian stretch) using a web interface accessible from any device able to connect to a WiFi generate by the Raspberry Pi.

Idealy, once you're connected to this WiFi with your device (smartphone, tablette or computer), you could control the Raspberry just by going to his IP adress with any browser you want.

Okay but the thing is I want to do that in field condition without any internet access via an ethernet cable. I don't want to go on internet by creating an Hotspot to share a connexion, I just want to access and control the Raspberry.

So is this possible ?

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is to have a Raspberry Pi uses WiFi to allow other devices to connect to it, a kind of WiFi access point, on its own network without any connection to the internet. Some other device would see the Raspberry Pi WiFi and connect to the Raspberry Pi using WiFi and then have access to a web server on the Raspberry Pi which provides an interface with a web service or perhaps just a web page with a form, to make changes to settings of the Raspberry Pi. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe this is functionally duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/62062/71180 since what you want is just the basic AP setup without routing, however that question doesn't have an accepted answer so cannot flag as dupe

Comment: @RichardChambers Exactly !

Comment: As per what everyone else has said, you can create an "access point" that is simply access to a local subnet (which might be just the AP machine and a single client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no requirement that you set up a bridge or router with your wifi hotspot configuration, but this is a common thing so often included in examples. Simply skip the bridging portion of any guide or tutorial you are following

Creating a Wifi hotspot with internet access requires bridging to another interface  with internet access e.g. wired Ethernet.

The hotspot and radio mode is managed by Linux wireless tools and drivers, routing is managed by the kernel directly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break the problem in to two part (a) and (b) solutions.

(a) You want to offer a wireless AP to others from your RPi
(b) You want to be able to *directly* connect to your RPi to control, change it but not using the wireless AP, correct?

If so I suggest you solve both separately. Get your wireless AP to work first.  Then you could for example enable Ether over USB - to directly connect to your RPi and control it.