# Disable Wireless Access Point to connect to Wifi Network

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

I've followed [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) guide on how to create a Wireless Access Point. Now I want to modify the behaviour as follows:

1. If the `home` network is available, don't create a new network and connect to it.
2. If the `home` network isn't avaiable, create a new network.
   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example how to [Switch between WiFi client and access point without reboot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93312/79866). But it is only for manual switching. It does not detect a hotspot to automatically connect to it and switch off the access point. To make it possible, the wpa_supplicant client service must always run so it can detect an available hotspot nearby. You can only switch on/off the access point in addition to the client service. So you have first to setup a [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) or [Access point as WiFi repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95072/79866). Then you could use **wpa_cli** running as daemon with option `-a` to detect a connection to a hotspot and switch on/off the access point on the RasPi. A generic example of doing this you can find at [Run a script when WiFi is connected to a particular wifi network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96077/79866).

If you use only the built-in WiFi device and not an additional USB/WiFi dongle, you should take note that switching the access point will also interrupt the client connection to the remote hotspot for a short time. This is due to a hardware/firmware limitation of the WiFi device. It shouldn't bother very much because you just connect to the hotspot. But if it isn't acceptable, you have to use an additional USB/WiFi dongle.

Answer (score 0):

I did develop a solution which did this, **BUT** while it did work with the onboard WiFi interfaces it is a kludge, so I can not recommend it as a reliable solution.

[Raspberry Pi to configure automatically as an Access Point OR WiFi client](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94985/8697).

It is far simpler to change modes using `systemd-networkd`.
This requires a total change to networking and more manual configuration, and I am not sure if there is a solution which automatically switches. You should study Ingo's many posts to see if one of these meets your needs.

If you did want to explore this, I suggest you first migrate to `systemd-networkd`. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117843/8697 describes a relatively simple setup which works as well as `dhcpcd`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So it seems like there isn't a easy way to achieve this. I'm just developing on a Pi3 connected to the home network via Ethernet instead of a Pi Zero