# Raspberry Pi Zero with WLAN Dongle, set up standalone AP and switch to Wifi Client

Tags: pi-zero, dhcp, access-point, hostapd, systemd-networkd

For a current project, I want to set up a standalone Blynk-Server on my Raspberry Pi Zero (version without inbuilt WLAN). I am using an EDIMAX Wifi Dongle EW-7811Un V2 and was able to set up the standalone Hotspot, with help of:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

and by following this forum and deleting the file for the blocked adapter as suggested by DannyMTK commented on 23 Sep 2019 in GitHub:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2979

Up to now, this is fine. However, when I wanted to set up the Blynk Server I realized, I need an Internet Connection for downloading the Java Package, etc.

So I followed this nice guideline from Ingo:
[Switch between wifi client and access point without reboot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93311/switch-between-wifi-client-and-access-point-without-reboot/93312#93312)

But no luck, I can't get it to work. How I configure the Pi to change into a wifi client for grabbing updates, packages, and other stuff?

The plan is to switch between standalone AP/Wifi Client only for grabbing updates. Normally the Pi stays as a standalone hotspot.

Thanks before.

Greets Maximilian

Comment: Have you considered adding a second wifi adapter for internet access?

Comment: Hi Steve. Up to now, no. Maybe this would help, but I wanted to keep the solution small in terms of hardware. So the idea is to have one Wifi-Adapter for configuration. If I am connected via Wifi to the Raspberry Pi, I can config it via SSH. If I am at home, I want to change the Pi into a Wifi Client and update packages if necessary. What still confuses me... how to connect the access point configuration, with the virtual AP tutorial suggested by Ingo. How can I interconnect these two tutorials to make things work?

Comment: If you are changing networks as well as configuration you can set up multiple WiFi connections and the Pi can automatically switch networks.

Comment: Hi Steve,

This is clear. But how? I tried first the tutorial to do a standalone hotspot, but then I can't access to the internet anymore. So I tried the tutorial from Ingo first, before adding the standalone hotspot. But I can't switch between hotspot and WiFi client. So I think I do something wrong. I will try again, but what I don't understand.. to switch to a standalone hotspot it first have to be configured? .. 
It seems like the chicken egg problem.

The essential question is how I can interconnect these two Tutorials to make the things work like you suggested.
Greets Maximilian

Comment: with a second WiFi adapter, you wouldn't have to. You would use one for Internet and one as hotspot.